# What is the homology class of this geodesic in the modular curve $X_0(11)$?

Tags: number-theory, homology-cohomology, hyperbolic-geometry

Very roughly, my question is: given a geodesic in the modular curve $X_0(11)$, how do you find its homology class?

In more detail: a convenient way to specify a geodesic in $X_0(11)$ is to first specify a geodesic in the completed upper-half plane $\mathbf{H}^* = \mathbf{H} \cup \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Q})$ and then push it forward to $X_0(11)$ under the natural map $$\mathbf{H}^* \to X_0(11).$$ In my case, I'm looking at the geodesic in $\mathbf{H}^*$ connecting the rational number $\frac{1}{11} \in \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Q})$ to the point $\infty \in \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Q})$ in the completed upper half plane $\mathbf{H}^*$. (This geodesic is just a vertical line connecting $\frac{1}{11}$ to $\infty$ in the upper half plane.)

The points $\frac{1}{11}$ and $\infty$ are $\Gamma_0(11)$-equivalent so they are sent to the same point of $X_0(11)$ under the natural map $\mathbf{H}^* \to X_0(11)$. Therefore, the geodesic connecting them becomes a *loop* in $X_0(11)$. I want to know: *what is the homology class of this loop?* That is, which "hole" of the torus $X_0(11)$ does it surround, and how many times does it go around that hole?

I'm quite stuck as to how to answer this. It seems to me that we only have information about the start and end points of the geodesic, and there's some strange topological weirdness going on in the middle that I don't know how to get my hands around. I've tried looking at the image of the geodesic in a fundamental domain for $X_0(11)$, but that hasn't been too successful either. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :) Thank you very much, friends!

---

*EDIT*: I've been asked to provide a picture of the fundamental domain of $X_0(11)$, so here it is:

[image]

The fundamental domain is the area above the green and blue circles on the bottom, and contained within the red lines on either side. The sides of the same colors are identified. If you make these identifications, you'll get a torus with two points missing, which corresponds to the fact that $X_0(11)$ has two cusps. Also, the circles have diameters $1/3, 1/6, 1/6,$ and $1/3$ respectively from left to right, totalling to a length of $1$.

The difficulty is, the geodesic I'm interested in isn't contained in the fundamental domain so I can't see what its image in the torus would be. Furthermore, I can't seem to figure out what its image in the fundamental domain would be. (This is because there any infinitely many matrices in $\Gamma_0(11)$, it is not clear how to know which matrix brings the geodesic connecting $\frac{1}{11}$ to $\infty$ into the fundamental domain.)

Comment: I believe that the concept solving your problem is that of *modular symbol*. But I'm not entirely sure of their properties myself so I hesitate to offer a fully-fledged argument. I *think* that this loop is not contractible, because a homotopy ""should"" lift to $\mathbb{H}^{*}$, with an obvious obstruction. Another way of finding a potential contradiction is to integrate a differential along this loop (so, a modular form of weight $2$ and level $11$) along this loop. If it doesn't vanish, the loop is not contractible.

Comment: Without a more detailed description of a fundamental domain of $X_0(11)$, your question is hard to answer. You do seem to have a more detailed description at hand, i.e. you mention a fundamental domain, and you mention that it's a torus. I suggest that you add a description of the fundamental to your question, the more explicit the better; the question should be pretty easy to answer then.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for the suggestion, I'll add a description of the fundamental domain to the question.

Comment: @LeeMosher I've just added a picture of the fundamental domain with some supporting details, so hopefully it should be clearer now.

Comment: You can do this by hand. Roughly speaking, letting $D_0$ be the fundamental domain that is shown, the transformations of $D_0$ under the action of the group $\Gamma_0(11)$ tile the whole of $\bf H$. You have to find the correct sequence of tiles $D_0,D_1,...$ whose union contains the geodesic in question. The next tile $D_1$ will be the one that meets $D_0$ along the left hand green circle where the line $x=\frac{1}{11}$ exits $D_0$. Now examine $D_0 \cup D_1$ to see if it yet contains the whole of the geodesic in question. If not, find $D_2$ next...

Comment: This sequence of tiles will eventually end, when you find the one having a cusp right at $\frac{1}{11}$.

Comment: I see. This is very helpful, thank you! Two follow-up questions: 1) is there a systematic way of finding a tile that borders $D_0$? Or is the process just trial-and-error, just applying various matrices to $D_0$ until we get a tile that borders $D_0$ by the green circle? 2) Is there a proof you know of that this sequence of tiles eventually ends?

Comment: The same procedure by which one determines the fundamental domain will also determine the three side matching transformations. For that purpose is probably very much worth your while to learn the details, with proofs, of that procedure.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! This was very helpful.